# Can't access public property in authService from one of its methods

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm creating an angular auth service.
I have this service with a public variable (I need public because I use it in many components) that's the logged user and I want to update this variable after login/logout.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService implements OnInit{
  public loggedUser: firebase.User;

  constructor(private firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.loggedUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  } ....
```

I have all the functions in the service:

```
signup(email: string, password: string) {
    this.firebaseAuth
      .auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(value => {
        console.log('Success!', value);
        this.loggedUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.warn('Something went wrong:',err.message);
      });    
  }

  login(email: string, password: string) {
    this.firebaseAuth
      .auth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(value => {
        console.log('Nice, it worked!');
        this.loggedUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.warn('Something went wrong:',err.message);
      });
  }
```

and they work smoothly. But with facebook auth:

```
facebooklogin(){
    var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    this.firebaseAuth
    .auth
    .signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
      // This gives you a Facebook Access Token. You can use it to access the Facebook API.
      var token = (<any> result).credential.accessToken;
      // The signed-in user info.
      var userResult = result.user;
      this.loggedUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      console.log(userResult,token)
    }).catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      // The email of the user's account used.
      var email = error.email;
      // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
      var credential = error.credential;
      // ...
      console.warn(errorCode,errorMessage,email,credential)
    });
  }
```

I get an error while assigning the currentUser to loggedUser: "Cannot set property 'loggedUser' of undefined". So it's like if it's not recognized. If I console.log this, I get undefined in fact. How's that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an arrow function for this as similar to your previous 2 functions

```
facebooklogin(){
    var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    this.firebaseAuth
    .auth
    .signInWithPopup(provider).then(result => {

    }).catch(error =>{

    });
  }
```

or if you wish to go in the same way first define a variable self exterior to the callback and then refer self within the callback

```
facebooklogin(){
    var self = this
    var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    this.firebaseAuth
    .auth
    .signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
           //self.loggedin
    }).catch(function(error) {

    });
  }
```